# How to calculate the relevancy

Tags: relevant-logic

I am trying to calculate the relevancy for below strategies.

- I have the "Keywords". I like to match against the post tile and post content. Using that Match I like to calculate the Relevancy. I wish to high high score if keyword exist in title compare to content match.

Example :-

Keyword : **Lorem**

> ***Lorem*** Ipsum content
>
> ***Lorem*** Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. ***Lorem*** Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s.

Relevancy 1 = ?

- I have the list of "Author Names". I want to check Author name against the post author. If there is match, I want to give some relevancy score.

Relevancy 2 = ?

Now I got two relevancy scores. From that I want calculate the over all score. I may add some more in this part. So is there any general formula to calculate the relevancy. Can Some one guide me!

Comment: Are you looking for a specific, very accurate statistical method? Or something rather empirical? In your first example I'd go as follows. You have a fixed chain of words, which if I counted correctly are 28. Assume each word has the same probability to appear. Then $P(Lorem)=1/28$. Since it appeared 3 times then its relevance is $R(Lorem)=3/28$. Of course this is not very formal, but maybe the idea helps. Then you can compare, for example $R(Lorem)=R(Ipsum)>R(text)$. Note: I used probability just to give a "feeling" not really meaning it was a mathematically correct argument.